# Oracle query to extract distinct routes

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

Burning out a brain cell... there has to be a simple way to do this.

I've inherited the following tables:

```
approval_path
approval_path_steps
applications
application_roles
requests
role_approvals
```

A user *`requests`* an *`application role`* for an *`application`*, which must go through an *`approval path`*, the steps of which are defined in *`approval_path_steps`*.  The approval history for each step of the approval path is stored in *`role_approvals`*.  So:

```
    approval_path:
    -> (p)approval_path_id 
   |                            
    -------------------------
                             |
    approval_path_steps:     |
       (p)approval_path_id --|
 -->   (p)sequence_nbr       |
|         approver           |
|                            |
|                            |
|   applications:            |
|   -> (p)application_id     |
|  |      approval_path_id --
|  |
|   -------------------------
|                            |
|   application_roles:       |
|   -> (p)role_id            |
|  |      application_id  ---   
|  |                        
|   -------------------------
|                            |
|   requests:                |
|   -> (p)request_nbr        |
|  |      role_id         --- 
|  |      requestor
|  |
|   -------------------------
|                            |
|   role_approvals:          |
|      (p)request_nbr     --- 
 ----  (p)sequence_nbr        (NOT ACTUALLY KEYED!!!  ENTERED MANUALLY!!)
          approver
          status
```

where `(p)` indicates the primary key.  Fields not immediately relevant have been omitted.  (btw, this was not my design)

**The problem:**  Approval path steps have changed over time for a given approval path; steps have been added, removed, or changed from one approver to another.  Therefore, the *`approval_path_steps`* that were actually taken for a request don't match the *`approval_path_steps`* that are currently defined for the requested role's *`approval_path`*.

**What I need:**  I need to query the `role_approvals` table in such a way that I can list the distinct paths that *were* used.  So:

```
role_approvals
--------------
 1000  role1  1  manager    approved
 1000  role1  2  hr_mgr     approved
 1000  role1  3  app_owner  approved

 1001  role1  1  manager    approved
 1001  role1  2  hr_mgr     approved
 1001  role1  3  app_owner  approved

 1002  role1  1  app_owner  approved
 1002  role1  2  manager    approved
```

**The results I want**:

```
id  seq_nbr  approver
--  -------  --------
 1        1  manager
 1        2  hr_mgr
 1        3  app_owner

 2        1  app_owner
 2        2  manager
```

where 'id' can be calculated in some identifying way, it doesn't matter how, to identify that unique approval path that was taken.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a partial solution.  Sadly, I am getting ORA-600 errors when I try to build on this to convert it back into the original format.  But at least it will get you the distinct paths.

Basically, it seems you need to aggregate the approver text field by the request number, and find distinct values of the aggregate.  XML functions are the only (built-in) text aggregation method that I know of in Oracle 10g.

```
select
  distinct xmlserialize(CONTENT approver_path AS VARCHAR2(2000)) distinct_path
from (
  select
    request_nbr,
    xmlagg(xmlelement("Approver",approver) order by sequence_nbr) approver_path
  from
    role_approvals
  group by
    request_nbr
)
```

Comment: This query dimmed the lights all morning (no surprise).  Going to try leaving it running overnight to see what I get back, I will get back to you.  Thanks!

Comment: I haven't been able to get this query to complete successfully... most I've been able to let it run is 14 hours, but I had to kill it when I packed up my laptop in the morning.  Marking it as the correct answer on the assumption it would work with a smaller set of data.  Thanks for the help!